# Mongo Aggregation multiple sorting stages (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to build complex aggregation pipeline, which will fetch items from collection and sort them multiple times.

What I need is to:
1) get all users from collection
2) sort them by user-selected value (f.e. by amount of comments they left)
3) sort them by role (admin, moderator, basic-user)

Idea is to show admin user first even if some basic user have more comments, but if we have 2 admins - they would be sorted too.

Note that first $sort is to avoid unexpected sort+limit behavior, when items aren't fetched in constant order. Value of $skip is calculated while building pipeline depending on page number passed in API request.

For now I have something like this:

```
[
  { $match: <some condition> },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
  { $sort: { countOfComment: -1 } },
  { $sort: { isAdmin: -1, isModerator: -1 } },
  { $skip: <page * 10> },
  { $limit: 10 }
]
```

If I got it right - it should:
1) get all users sorted by id, so there would be no duplications in different pages. this requires unique field to work
2) sort by amount of comments
3) sort by user role. It meant to save previous sorting results, so

```
- user with 4 comments
- moderator with 0 comments
- admin with 3 comments
- user with 2 comments
- admin with 1 comment
```

would become

```
- admin with 3 comments
- admin with 1 comment
- moderator with 0 comments
- user with 4 comments
- user with 2 comments
```

But it doesn't. Looks like each next $sort statement loses results of previous one. Any ideas how to reach desired behavior?

Comment: Merge all the `$sort` stages into one `{ $sort: { countOfComment: 1, isAdmin: -1, isModerator: -1 } },`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I've tried it with no luck, but I think I should give it another chance and play with order of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one sort stage, and that is,

```
    $sort: {
      isAdmin: -1,
      isModerator: -1,
      countOfComment: -1
    }
```

Basically, since you've sorted by countOfComment first, then the highest priority will be given to sorting by countOfComment. So, no matter what, the countOfComment field will definitely be sorted in descending order and only then will it see the next field to sort. Similarly, the last field will get the least priority while sorting.

The order in which you place the sort items is the order of priority.

Comment: Does it mean that I can still keep multiple $sort stages, but reorder them? Anyway, this answer helped me so I will check it as right.

Comment: Another question is that I've read that JS objects aren't ordered. It works, but can I actually relate on order of key:value pairs there?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge sort in one object like:-

```
{ $sort: { countOfComment: 1, isAdmin: -1, isModerator: -1 } }
```

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for removing duplicate records and then use project and after that use the sort

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what do you mean by 'duplicate records'?

Comment: You're saying there should be no duplication records in the pagination, then that's why I recommend you to use $group

Comment: I think I used term 'duplications' in wrong way. It looked that with same sorting parameters page N and page N+1 can contain few similar listings.